# Find the Angle of elevation

Tags: trigonometry

A pillar is leaning towards east and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the angles of elevation of the top of the pillar
from two points due west of the pillar at distances $a$ and $b$ respectively. Find the angle between the pillar and the horizontal.

I started by fixing the directions,but don't  west and east directions lie on a line? Then how can I find the angle of elevation?  This is the diagram provided in the answer: [image: Reference Image]

Comment: Can you find $x$ in terms of $a, b, \alpha, \beta$?

Comment: In the figure, east is to the right, west is to the left

Comment: Write equations for $\tan \alpha$ and $\tan \beta$.  You get two equations in two unknowns

Comment: @sudeep5221 yeah I can

Comment: Using this, you can also find $h$ in terms of given parameters and then the angle of elevation is $\tan^{-1}(h/x)$.